# Error includePath of VsCode "cannot open source file"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is the tree of my project simplified.

In my case when I open the file dg.cpp I get the error : cannot open source file "KS/dg.hpp "C/C++(1696)
at the line : #include "KS/dg.hpp".

in my includePath in c_cpp_properties.json i have : "${workspaceFolder}/**"

But everything works fine when compiling via my makefile.

Also everything works fine when I do an Alt+O to switch from dg.cpp to dg.hpp I can't figure out what is causing the problem and how to fix it? It doesn't cause any error but it's annoying not to have the links between files

```bash
.
├── KS
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── dg.hpp
│   │   ├── KS -> .
│   │   ├── node1.hpp
│   ├── makefile
│   └── src
│       ├── dg.cpp
│       ├── node1.cpp
├── main.cpp
├── makefile
```

Thank you !

Comment: how does that even work? There is no such relative path `KS/dg.hpp` anywhere in what you have shown.

Comment: The compilation ? 
Or the vscode search file includePath ?

Comment: oh... I see the symlink now. Interesting trick (though I personally wouldn't use it. looks like a great way to confuse tooling)

Answer (score 0):

I found my error :

Inside the c_cpp_properties.json I update the includePath to :

```json
"includePath": [
"${workspaceFolder}/**",
"${workspaceFolder}/KS/include",
],
```

Now VsCode seems to make links properly.